# Strange behavior of JAVAGC

Tags: java, garbage-collection

i have the following code :

```
public class MyOjbect {
public Integer z = 111;
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("invoking GC in MyOjbect");
    super.finalize();
         }
     }
      public class GC {
private MyOjbect o; 
private void doSomethingElse(MyOjbect obj) {
    o = obj;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void doSomething() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Start");
    MyOjbect o = new MyOjbect();        
     doSomethingElse(o);        
     o = new MyOjbect();
     doSomethingElse(null);
     System.gc();
    // System.out.println("checking "+o.z);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    GC gc = new GC();
    gc.doSomething();
       }
}
```

I wonder why the `GC` garbage the `o` variable after executing the `doSomethingElse` method. Even the `o` variable is not yet null. In fact, when i debug the code `o` after `doSomethingElse`  is not null but the `GC` garbage it. In addition if i uncomment the last line, GC print the `o.z` variable and after that invoke the GC.

**Updated** :  For people who asks why the local variable is the same as the field.I have just copied a question from the SCJP Test Exam as it is

Comment: Can you clean up and format your code?  And then rewrite it without ambiguity?  It's confusing the issue that you use `o` twice, once as a field name and once as a variable name, when they have no effect on each other.  I suspect even you don't know which `o` you're referring to at each point in your question.

Comment: btw a reference need not be `null` before the underlying object is garbage collected. If the object is not strongly reachable from any garbage collection root (pretty much a thread), it is eligible for collection even if it has incoming references.

Comment: i have just made a copy/paste from EXAM 310-065 Test.The original question is:

Comment: What does mean ?.GC garbages variables that still has references to it???

Comment: You dont g/c variables, you g/c object instances! And you create two objects, but only one gets gced... guess which one goes out of scope! (It becomes clear when you add a default constructor: 

public MyOjbect()
    {
        System.out.println("New MyObject: "  + this);
    }

and this to finalize(): 

System.out.println("invoking GC in MyOjbect: " + this);

Comment: Thanks Gyro it's the right answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of subjects to discuss here !

First, as Gyro said, The GC does not collect variables. It collects instances of dead objects. A dead object is an object that has no strong reference (variable) that leads to it. Note that there are more subtle cases (Weak references, Soft references, Phantom references, ...), but let's focus on the most common case :-) You can find more information about this here : https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references

If you uncomment the last line, "111" gets printed since o is the local variable that references an instance of MyObject you created with `o = new MyOjbect();`.

Now, the trickiest thing : you have two different instances of MyObject. However, your program only print once the "invoking GC in MyObject". It becomes evident if you transform your "MyObject" class like this :

```
public class MyOjbect {
    public Integer z = 111;

    public MyOjbect() {
        System.out.println("Creating MyObject " + hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("invoking GC in MyOjbect " + hashCode());
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

You program now prints two MyObjects creation but only one that is recovered by the GC. This is because there is absolutely no guarantee that the finalize() method will be called. According to the JLS and the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29) of finalize() :

> The Java programming language does not guarantee which thread will
>   invoke the finalize method for any given object

In your case, the end of the application makes every object dead. No need to run a GC since the heap will be completely recovered once the JVM exits.

Comment: It's some bit confusing.Why the GC garbages objects that still references.In other way,GC free the memory case occuped by the o variable that's why we see the "invoking GC in MyOjbect" but after that i can print z integer of my o variable.Can any one clarify this to me?

Comment: No, you have two instances of "MyObject". The first one gets collected but the second one does not, therefore the `z` integer is still available.